# MEMORY ISSUE: MemoryError: Unable to allocate array with shape (4104, 1048576, 3) and data type int32

Tags: python, numpy

I have a working code as shown below, but when my rgbL is very huge I got this error:  MEMORY ISSUE: MemoryError: Unable to allocate array with shape (4104, 1048576, 3) and data type int32

How to fix this one?

```
sh = img.shape
img = img.reshape(-1, 3)
img[np.where(((rgbL[:,None,:]-img)==0).all(axis=2))[1]]=np.array([255,0,0])
img = img.reshape(sh)
```

where img and rgbL is defined as:

```
img:
[[20  45  40]
[ 30  45  60]
[  0   1   2]
[ 70  50 100]
[  4   5   6]]
rgbL:
[[ 20,  45,  40],
[ 30,  45,  60],
  ..........
[ 70,  50, 100]]
```

Comment: 4104 * 1048576 * 3 * 4 = 48GiB do you have that much RAM?  there also needs to space for all the other variables in your program and other running programs / OS

Comment: It's too big, simply put. If you go to uint8 it'll trim that down to 12GiB, and that's still a lot. You may need to memory map your array to a local file to work with it.

Comment: Yah that is my problem.  I think one best solution is to work with my list by batch.